# Windows Authentication to log into Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 App using Identity to manage users. Now the requirement is to also support Windows Authentication. If a Windows user has an account in Identity an automatic login should take place. I think I need to generate an Identity cookie in this situations but don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use both Identity and Windows Auth at the same time. The best you can do is attempt to auth the user via an LDAP connection to your AD server. In short, the user would still need to explicitly sign in, but they could use their domain credentials to do so.

The situation is a little better if you implement IdentityServer. This is a bit more effort, but it can pay dividends in the future from having a centralized auth service (allowing you service APIs, mobile apps, etc.). IdentityServer can handle Windows Auth, but it treats it as an external sign in provider, like Google, Facebook, etc. You'd have a button or whatever to login via Windows, and then it would seamlessly authorize the user. See the [IdentityServer docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/windows.html) for more information on that setup.

Comment: I know that this would be no best practice but I think it can be realised. Also because @Tratcher wrote such proposal here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749710/is-asp-net-core-identity-needed-for-intranet-app-using-windows-authentication#comment86519053_49749710